# Python regex negative lookbehind behaviour

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to parse a document that contains a list of headers and subheaders followed by bodies of text. The file would look something like this:

> HEADER ONE:  Some text within header one.
>
> HEADER TWO: Some text within header two.  More lines of text within
>   header two.
>
> 1. SUBHEADER INSIDE HEADER TWO:  Some text within subheader two.

I'm trying to pull a list of all of the headers (but not subheaders). As you can see from the example above, all the headers are composed of all caps letters followed by a colon. The subheaders start with a number, a period, two spaces, and then all caps letters followed by a colon.

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't seem to be working. It picks up all three HEADER ONE, HEADER TWO, and SUBHEADER INSIDE HEADER TWO as headers. I want it to just pick up HEADER ONE and HEADER TWO as the two headers:

```
import re

file = open('inputFile', 'r')
document = file.read()

match = re.findall('(?<!\d\.  )([A-Z ]+:)', document)

print match
```

Current output: ['HEADER ONE:', 'HEADER TWO:', '  SUBHEADER INSIDE HEADER TWO:']
Desired output: ['HEADER ONE:', 'HEADER TWO:']

I tried to use negative lookbehind, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get the desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: I think in this case it might be easier to process the file line by line, and check each line. If the line starts with spaces, you know it cannot be a header.

Comment: won't https://regex101.com/r/eD6pG1/1 suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing anchor in your regex. Try

```
^(?<!\d\. )([A-Z\s]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD6pG1/3)**

You should use space() instead of `\s`

You can also use positive lookahead as

```
^(?=[A-Z\s]+:)([A-Z\s]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD6pG1/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/T5KWQf)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew to be truthful, I just wanted to stick to OP's format here..though i should have included those

Comment: Thanks, but the reason that I don't use the anchor is that since I'm using file.read(), it reads in the whole file at once, so the regex is applied to all the text in the file as opposed to each line at a time. With that in mind, do you know why my regex isn't excluding the subheader? Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, oh wait nevermind, please disregard my last comment. I didn't see the modifiers that you added to the regex, which made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> All the headers are composed of all caps letters followed by a colon.

So, you need a very basic regex:

```
(?m)^([A-Z\s]+):
```

However, it may match even those lines that only start with whitespace and a colon. Use a more precise version:

```
(?m)^([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI2zP4/1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?m)` - inline `re.MULTILINE` modifier to make `^` match the beginning of a *line*
- `^` - start of a line
  -`([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)` - Group 1 (only the value matched with this group will appear in the `re.findall` results) matching

  - `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more uppercase letters
  - `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*` - zero or more sequences of 1+ whitespace (`\s+`) followed with 1+ uppercase letters `[A-Z]+`
- `:` - a colon

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/UEMdFV):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?m)^([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):')
s = """HEADER ONE: Some text within header one.

HEADER TWO: Some text within header two. More lines of text within header two.
    1. SUBHEADER INSIDE HEADER TWO: Some text within subheader two.
"""
res = p.findall(s)
print(res)     # => ['HEADER ONE', 'HEADER TWO']
```